# Are the number of states available equal to the number of particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states, quantum-hall-effect

Let's say we have a 2d sea of electrons. The energy states of these electrons will be quantised because of some sort of boundary condition on the system, and therefore there are only an integer number of available energy eigenstates. Therefore, assuming that all electrons occupy an energy eigenstate (Which is an assumption I'm struggling to validate). Would the number of available states equal the number of electrons in this system?

If this is true I'm struggling to understand why. Just because there are that many available states doesn't mean there will be that many electrons occupying those states does it?

Comment: Answer to title: no. The dimension of the Hilbert space of $N$ electrons is $\binom {d}{N}$, where $d$ is the dimension of the single-particle Hilbert space.

Comment: So in a two-dimensional system would that correspond to the number of particles being the number of eigenstates divided by 2 ?

Comment: The hydrogen atom has an infinite number of bound states.

Answer (score 4):

> Let's say we have a 2d sea of electrons.

Better yet, let's consider a 1d system. Better yet, let's consider the simplest 1d system, the ["particle in a box."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box)

If the "box" extends along the $x$ axis from $0$ to $L$, then the energy eigenstates [are the following countably infinite set of states, indexed by the natural number $n$](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Mechanics/05.5%3A_Particle_in_Boxes/Particle_in_a_1-Dimensional_box):
$$
\phi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(\frac{n\pi}{L}x)\tag{1}
$$

> Therefore, assuming that all electrons occupy an energy eigenstate (Which is an assumption I'm struggling to validate).

A single electron does *not* need to occupy a single energy eigenstate. In general, the single electronic state can be described as *any* linear superposition of the energy eigenstates:
$$
\Phi(x)=\sum_n \alpha_n \phi_n(x)\;,
$$
where the $\alpha_n$ are arbitrary complex numbers subject only to the condition $\sum_{n}|\alpha_n|^2 = 1$. In the special case where $\alpha_n = \delta_{n,m}$, then the electronic state is the energy eigenstate $\phi_m(x)$.

> Would the number of available states equal the number of electrons in this system?

No, this is not the case, since there are an infinite number of states, but not an infinite number of electrons.

> If this is true I'm struggling to understand why. Just because there are that many available states doesn't mean there will be that many electrons occupying those states does it?

The number of electrons you describe is your choice. The solutions to the Schrödinger equation just tell you the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.

Furthermore, in a case like "particle in a box," the eigenstates really only make sense for a single particle. If you were to choose to place, say, two electrons in the box you would further have to postulate that the electrons were non-interacting (which is quite an absurd assumption on its face, since electrons are charged and therefore interact.) This is because, the correct Hamiltonian of two electrons in a box is:
$$
\hat H = \frac{p_1^2}{2m}+\frac{p_2^2}{2m}+V(|x_1 - x_2|)\;,
$$
where $V(|x_1 - x_2|)$ is the interaction energy. But, the non-interacting PIAB Hamiltonian for two electrons is:
$$
\hat{H}_{non-interacting} = \frac{p_1^2}{2m}+\frac{p_2^2}{2m}\;.
$$

---

If you were to consider $N$ electrons and you were to assume that the $N$ electrons were non-interacting. And if you further were to assume that the electrons have spin-1/2, (which they do). The single-particle energy eigenstates are:
$$
\psi_{n,m_s}(x,\sigma) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(\frac{n\pi}{L}x)\chi_{m_s}(\sigma)\;, \tag{2}
$$
where $m_s$ can take on two values (say, "up" and "down"), and where we see that the RHS of Eq.(2) is nearly identical to the RHS of Eq. (1) other than a factor of $\chi_{m_s}$ to track the spin degeneracy, and where $\sigma\in\left\{1,2\right\}$ is a variable in the two-dimensional spin space. (E.g., $\chi_{\uparrow}$ can be represented by $\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\chi_{\downarrow}$ can be represented by $\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right)$. E.g. $\chi_{\uparrow}(1)=1$ and $\chi_{\uparrow}(2)=0$.)

For this $N$-electron system the total (non-interacting) Hamiltonian is just $N$ copies of the single-particle Hamiltonian.

In this non-interacting case, the *lowest* energy eigenstate of the combined system of $N$ particles, and which also obeys the "exclusion principle," would *seemingly* be the product of the *lowest* $N/2$ single-particle energy eigenstates. That is, seemingly:
$$
\Psi_0^{(N)}(x_1,\sigma_1,x_2,\sigma_2,\ldots, x_N,\sigma_N) \stackrel{?}{=} 
\psi_{1,\uparrow}(x_1,\sigma_1)
\psi_{1,\downarrow}(x_2,\sigma_2)
\psi_{2,\uparrow}(x_3,\sigma_3)
\psi_{2,\downarrow}(x_4,\sigma_4)
\ldots
\psi_{N/2,\uparrow}(x_{N-1},\sigma_{N-1})
\psi_{N/2,\downarrow}(x_{N},\sigma_N)\;.
$$

However, the above energy eigenstate is actually the wrong state, since it does not take into account the [(perhaps lesser known) symmetrization axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle#Connection_to_quantum_state_symmetry) of many-particle quantum mechanics. (The "exclusion principle" is a consequence of the symmetrization axiom.) The correct, non-interacting, lowest energy eigenstate is the [Slater determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_determinant):
$$
\Psi_0^{(N)}(x_1,\sigma_1,x_2,\sigma_2,\ldots, x_N,\sigma_N)=\left|\begin{matrix}\psi_{1,\uparrow}(x_1,\sigma_1) & \psi_{1,\downarrow}(x_1,\sigma_1) & \ldots & \psi_{N/2,\downarrow}(x_1,\sigma_1)\\
\psi_{1,\uparrow}(x_2,\sigma_2) & \psi_{1,\downarrow}(x_2,\sigma_2) & \ldots & \psi_{N/2,\downarrow}(x_2,\sigma_2)\\
\ldots\\
\psi_{1,\uparrow}(x_N,\sigma_N) & \psi_{1,\downarrow}(x_N,\sigma_N) & \ldots & \psi_{N/2,\downarrow}(x_N,\sigma_N)\\
\end{matrix}\right|\;.\tag{3}
$$

Because we are often only able to prepare systems in the ground state (or approximately in the ground state), we are often very interesting in the ground state.

For a state like the Slater determinant in Eq. (3) we say that the single-particle states appearing in the determinant are "occupied" and the other states are "unoccupied."

---

As a final note, despite the seeming absurdity of the non-interacting electron postulate, it has been applied in atomic and solid state physics as a good first approximation in some cases. The reason why one can approximately treat the electrons as non-interacting is due to many-body effects like "screening." Indeed, in some solid state systems the electron-electron repulsion can be screened enough to allow for an lattice-mediated attraction to form bound pairs of electrons called "cooper pairs!"